# Change in `<Output>' element with if condition

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-output

I have two input files like:

**a.xml**

```
<a>
   <data>...</data>
</a>
```

**b.xml**

```
<b>
   <data>...</data>
</b>
```

**my xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to check first root element, if it is `<a>` than `<xsl:output>` is

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

else

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="us-ascii" indent="no"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, XSLT is XML so you can of course use XSLT to create another XSLT with the desired output encoding and you can then run it in a separate step.

As an alternative you could check the root element not being an `a` element and then delegate outputting to `xsl:result-document` where you can change the `encoding`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document-node()[*[not(self::a)]]">
        <xsl:result-document encoding="US-ASCII">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y8

Comment: Thanks @Martin, it works online, but when i try this in oxygen18 with saxon 9.6 it doesn't work can you suggest.

Comment: What exactly happens with Saxon 9.6, do you get an error?

Comment: no, not an error, it gives output as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><b>
    <data>abcáéú€</data>
</b>`

Comment: It also seems to work at http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vA with Saxon 9.5 so I am astonished that you say it doesn't work in oXygen with Saxon 9.6. You might want to try it outside of oXygen with your preferred Saxon version, if it works there then I think it is better asking in the oxygen support forum for reasons why the approach doesn't work inside Oxygen.

Comment: Thanks Martin, i have check this in other environment and it worked, seems it is an issue with oxygen.